# Consume multivalue Web Service, vb.net

Tags: web-services

I'm a newby using asp and webservice technologies. I'm trying to read a Web Service and work with data returned.

My Web Service returns many fields, so I'm looking for the best way to use this returned data.

The XML returned by my Web Service looks like this:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/wsexportaproducto/Productos">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Exportacion">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="gtin" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="gtinreemplazado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refidcateglobal" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refidcatelocal" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="gln" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="glnfabricante" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nombrefabricante" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refpaismercado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="iniciovigenciadn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="finvigenciadn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="vida" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nomproducto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="marca" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="descproducto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="descripcioncorta" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="profundo" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidprofundo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="alto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidalto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ancho" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidancho" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="pesobruto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidpesobruto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="pesoempaque" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidpesoempaque" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="contenidoneto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidcontenidoneto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="escontenidovariable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refembalaje" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esretornable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="factorestiba" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadminima" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="contenidos" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refpaisorigen" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadcolorcodigo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadcoloragencia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadcolor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtalleagencia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtallecodigo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtalle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadordenable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="cantminimapedir" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="multiplopedir" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esfacturable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadembarque" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nrocapasartcomercial" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nroartcomercialesporcapa" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidadesporpallet" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidporcapa" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nrodecapas" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="submarca" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtipo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="oferta" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="dscompania" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nombregen" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadsabor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="continentes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="reftiponivel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadconsumo" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="pesoneto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidpesoneto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="cantidadtotalcontenida" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="reftipogtin" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esprivado" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="statussecodat" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="accion" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="fechaaccion" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Exportacion diffgr:id="Exportacion1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<gtin>07500112045058</gtin>
<refidcateglobal>10005730</refidcateglobal>
<gln>7505000010064</gln>
<refpaismercado>484</refpaismercado>
<iniciovigenciadn>2012-08-09T00:00:00-05:00</iniciovigenciadn>
<finvigenciadn>4999-12-31T23:59:59-06:00</finvigenciadn>
<marca>PINTACOLOR</marca>
<descproducto>PINTACOLOR BLANCO</descproducto>
<descripcioncorta>PINTURA PINTACOLOR 18 L</descripcioncorta>
<profundo>40.000000000000000</profundo>
<unidprofundo>CM</unidprofundo>
<alto>60.000000000000000</alto>
<unidalto>CM</unidalto>
<ancho>40.000000000000000</ancho>
<unidancho>CM</unidancho>
<pesobruto>26.200000000000000</pesobruto>
<unidpesobruto>KG</unidpesobruto>
<unidpesoempaque>KG</unidpesoempaque>
<escontenidovariable>false</escontenidovariable>
<esretornable>false</esretornable>
<esunidadminima>true</esunidadminima>
<contenidos/>
<esunidadordenable>false</esunidadordenable>
<esfacturable>true</esfacturable>
<esunidadembarque>false</esunidadembarque>
<oferta>false</oferta>
<dscompania>DISTRIBUIDOR</dscompania>
<nombregen>PINTURA</nombregen>
<continentes/>
<reftiponivel>EA</reftiponivel>
<esunidadconsumo>false</esunidadconsumo>
<esprivado>false</esprivado>
<statussecodat>2</statussecodat>
</Exportacion>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

So far I have been able to read the webservice, here is the code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim SerSyncfonia As Syncfonia.Productos
        SerSyncfonia = New Syncfonia.Productos()

        Dim v1 = "7505000010064"
        Dim v2 = "DISTRIBU"
        Dim v3 = "DISTRIBU"
        Dim v4 = ""
        Dim v5 = "7500112045058"

        Label1.Text = SerSyncfonia.ObtieneProducto(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString
    End Try

End Sub
```

The result I'm getting for Label1.Text after pressing Button1 is "System.Data.DataSet"

So, after I read the Web Service, how can I store this data somewhere to be able to work with data. For example, get the value of the **nombregen** element, or **gtin** element and store them somewhere.

Comment: Is this an ASMX web service, or WCF? Are you using "Add Service Reference", or "Add Web Reference"?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a bad idea to pass the `DataSet` class or any other type specific to .NET when using web services. That makes them only usable by compatible versions of .NET (not Java, for instance).

In your case, though, there's a simpler question: even if a DataSet was successfully passed, what exactly did you expect the `ToString` method to do? Even without web services, `DataSet.ToString()` isn't going to produce useful output.